# did i mess up the battery

Tags: battery, charging

i drained the battery in my nokia lumia as told in store and i plugged it in to charge it for the 1st time and the phone just powered on so i put my pin in and used it for a half hour while it charged, its still charging now upstairs now, my question is by it turning on and me using it, have i messed up the battery? will it have a low charge on it all the time or what effect will it have on it?

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't hurt the battery at all. You're fine.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, it's good to keep your battery charged. In other words, there's no need to let it run down fully, just charge the phone or top up the charge when you can.

Comment: My understanding is that is actually bad for the battery to frequently fully discharge/charge it.

Comment: @row1 A lot of 'advice' comes from older NiCd type batteries. [Life Hacker has a good overview](http://lifehacker.com/5875162/how-often-should-i-charge-my-gadgets-battery-to-prolong-its-lifespan), and if you have lots of time, check out [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/)

Comment: @NeilTurner yeah the old advice for NiCad is pretty much the opposite of what I said. People in the shop still tell you that when you buy a new phone...